# Ubuntu/Drupal: PHP can not connect to other MsSQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, drupal-7

I copied one of our test servers and now I'm having a weird issue.

We have 2 MsSQL-servers, but I can only connect to one of them. I can not find any configuration issues that should cause this and other test server can connect to both fine. Any tips what could cause the issue and where to look?

The only clue is this in Drush logs:

```
 2744375  11/Mar 12:46  php       warning   Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: MY.SQL.SERVER in eval() (line 4 of /srv/drupal/modules/php/php.module(80) : eval()'d code).
```